# Joomla 3.x RSS syndication

Tags: joomla, rss

Folks,
I am having difficulties in limiting the RSS feed to just the intro text.

No matter what I do, I am still getting the full text of the articles.

- I have configured the Syndication Feeds module and published it to all pages (I tried a specific page - same result)
- In 'Articles Options' I have set the Integration tab to 'Show Intro Text' For each feed item
- In the Default Menu Item Integration tab, I have set 'Show Intro Text' For each feed item
- In the specific Menu Item I have set 'Show RSS Feed' (it is a K2 category item feed)

but still I get the full article.....  any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your content doesn't technically have an intro text. Check if you have an intro text in your articles - most like you don't (we had the exact same problem last week with a client).

In this case, you have 2 options: Either you manually add the "Read More" break in every article (by clicking on the "Insert Read More" button), or you programmatically modify the `view.feed.php` file (the file responsible for generating the feed) to get an excerpt. If you don't have many articles, then the former option is much better.

Comment: Hi, and thanks a million for your reply!  Both suggestions are simply excellent....  I will modify the view.feed.php file, since I may have quite a few articles...    thanks again...  it is greatly appreciated!